# What is wrong? DropDownList Asp.Net Mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**[HttpGet] ActionResult Edit**

```
Model model = dbContext.Table.Find(id);
ViewBag.MyID = new SelectList(dbContext.Table, "id", "value", model.value);
```

**View Edit**

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MyID)
```

**[HttpPost] ActionResult Edit**

```
public ActionResul Edit(..., string MyID)
```

**My Model**

```
[Table("tb_estados_uf")]
public class Estado
{
    [Key]
    public int uf_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estado")]
    public string uf_estado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UF")]
    public string uf_sigla { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Estado> ufIE { get; set; }
}
```

**This is the top of my view:**

```
@model Oficial.Models.Candidato
```

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include ="(Candidato's Columns)..., uf_id (FK)")] Candidato objCandidato, FormCollection fc, HttpPostedFileBase file, string MyID)
```

The problem is this parameter, **he's always 1**

even when its recorded with the last record of my database.

Have anything that am i forget?

sorry with my english

Comment: how do you post data from your form back to your server?

Answer (score 0):

Your models should be free of presentation attributes

```
[Table("tb_estados_uf")]
public sealed class Estado
{
    [Key]
    public int uf_id { get; set; }

    public string uf_estado { get; set; }

    public string uf_sigla { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Estado> ufIE { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create a separate view model for the purpose of collecting data from the user.

```
public sealed class EstadoViewModel
{
  public int uf_id { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Estado")]
  public string uf_estado { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "UF")]
  public string uf_sigla { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<Estado> ufIE { get; set; }
}
```

Your new view model:

```
public sealed class Candidato
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Phone { get; set; }
  public string OtherField { get; set; }
  public EstadoViewModel EstadoVM { get; set; }
}
```

Then on top of your View:

```
@model Oficial.Models.Candidato
```

Then add the drop down control in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EstadoVM.uf_sigla, Model.EstadoVM.ufIE, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
```

Finally in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResul Edit(Candidato model) 
{
  // Code action here
}
```

Comment: I'll edit my post with some others things

Comment: I tried with DropDownListFor and its work for bring others id (MyID), but I have an Error with this: 
dbContext.Entry(objCandidato).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges(); <<<<------ This line

Comment: My view is create an person and i need to select where he from like:
Name, Telephone blabla, and this dropdownlist is for state.
because of that, my top of my model is different from my other model 'Estado'

Am I being clear?

Sorry if this sounds ignorant, but I'm trying to be polite.

Comment: Yes, you can only use one model per view. For that reason you must add another view model to your model. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: now, i dont have access to my database, only tomorrow, but I'm grateful already, and tomorrow i say if its work :)

Comment: i got it, 
My Solution: 
Using files that i post first time here, i modified my candidato model, add this line public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EstadoList { get; set; }
My view: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.uf_id, Model.EstadoList, new { @class = "form-control"})
My Edit HttpGet: candidato.EstadoList = new SelectList(dbContext.Estados, "uf_id", "uf_estado");
My Edit HttpPost: get uf_id with the rest of mt 'candidato model' parameter

THANKS SO MUCH, even that i didn't use your solution, you help me to think better